# Can I search for a job and attend an interview in Canada?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, legal

Can I search for a job or attend a job interview on visitor visa, is it legal in Canada?

While applying from India do I need to mention it in my application form that I am visiting to Canada for job search purpose??

Comment: Note that due to COVID-19, Canada currently bars all "discretionary travellers" arriving from countries other than the US (and then only for immediate family members of Canadian citizens/permanent residents.)  Searching for a job is probably viewed as discretionary.

Answer (score 2):

While visitor visas are not meant to be used as a vehicle to find work in Canada, visitor visa holders are not expressly prohibited from searching for work while they’re in Canada. However, if you do choose to search for work while you’re on a visitor visa, you should keep the following in mind:

- Never conceal or falsify your reason for visiting Canada from an immigration officer
- You will be expected to prove your intention to return to your country when your visitor visa expires irrespective of the outcome of your search for work
- You will be expected to prove that you won’t work in Canada without a valid work permit

Source: https://www.canadim.com/blog/visiting-canada-can-do-visitor-visa/

Comment: How can you prove that you won't do something in the future?